# Python: Read all config values from .ini file and store in Dictionary and access in other files

Tags: python, visual-studio, pycharm, config

I have a config.ini file. When my python application starts, I want to read all config values and store them in a dictionary. Then this dictionary should be available in all other files

```
[sql]
Server=localhost
UserId=root
[url]
url1=localhost
UserId1=root
```

I have a Class1.py:

```
from configparser import SafeConfigParser

class class1(object):

    def __init__(self, *file_name):
        parser = SafeConfigParser()
        parser.read('config.ini')

        self.__config__ = {}
        for section in parser.sections():
            self.__dict__.update(parser.items(section)) 

configData= class1('config.ini')
```

In my main  file, I am not able to access configData.Server

`from class1 import configData
    print(configData.Server)`

Comment: Is your file named Class1.py or class1.py? Because you didn't capitalize it in your import statement.

Comment: @Sweater-Baron: it is class1.py

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, the config keys are automatically getting converted to lowercase. 
Even my key is `Server`, it is getting changed to `server`.

So while `configData.Server` throws error `configData.server` works fine.